# How to parse a DBus response, which is a complex data type?

Tags: c++, linux, dbus

I need to use the libdbus-cpp library to get an answer to the org method call `org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager GetManagedObjects`. His answer has the type `a{oa{sa{sv}}}`. If I understood correctly, I need to write the answer of this method to `std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, DBus::Variant>>>`. Most likely, this needs to be done using the dbus_message_iter_open_container function, but I don't understand how, and I haven't found any suitable examples on the web or in the official documentation. Please tell me how this can be done?

Comment: If you're already using dbus-cpp, isn't this a matter of specifying the appropriate result type for `invoke_method_synchronously`? The underlying `Codec<T>` specialization supports STL containers such as map and vector..

Comment: Please do not edit answers into the question body; post them as actual answers instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The most convenient way to do this is to call the Introspect method from the desired DBus object and save the output to a *.xml file. Then, we call `dbusxx-xml2cpp` with this *.xml file as an argument and generate a proxy class. We connect it to our project and voila. We can call any method of a given DBus object

Edit: Unfortunately, my answer only partially works. For methods with normal types, everything works fine, but when calling `GetManagedObject`, the program crashes into SEGFAULT, pointing to the library internals. For some reason, it cannot cast the value `[ ]` to the `DBus::Variant` ...

Edit: Found out what the problem is. This bug was in the library before version 0.9.0-11. And I worked with the library version 0.9.0-8. Updating the library package fixed this crash, so everything works. The question is closed